# StructureMap - Configure two different constructor for the same concrete class

Tags: structuremap

I have a problem configuring the constructor to be used in a class as parameter constructor in a service. 
I have two services that uses the same repository, the repository have two constructor, the first is used by the first service and the second is used by the second service.

I have isolate the problem in this example:

```
public interface IBookRepository { }

public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
{
    public BookRepository(string repositoryName, string dbName) { }
    public BookRepository(string repositoryName) { }
}

public interface IService1 { }

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public Service1(IBookRepository repo) { }
}

public interface IService2 { }

public class Service2 : IService2
{
    public Service2(IBookRepository repo) { }
}

public class StrucutreMapRegistry : Registry
{
    public StrucutreMapRegistry()
    {
        var x = this;

        x.For<IService1>().Use<Service1>()
            .Ctor<IBookRepository>().Is<BookRepository>(c =>
            {
                new Container(x2 => x2.SelectConstructor(() => new BookRepository("")));
                c.Ctor<string>("repositoryName").Is("RepositoryForService1ToDefaultDatabase");
            });

        x.For<IService2>().Use<Service2>()
            .Ctor<IBookRepository>().Is<BookRepository>(c =>
            {
                new Container(x2 => x2.SelectConstructor(() => new BookRepository("", "")));
                c.Ctor<string>("repositoryName").Is("RepositoryForService2ToOtherDatabase");
                c.Ctor<string>("dbName").Is("OtherDatabase");
            });

    }
}
```

I use "*new Container(x2 => x2.SelectConstructor(() => new BookRepository("")));*" in order to select the constructor but this statement select the constructor globally for all the uses.

How to select the correct constructor for each service configuration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have change  "new Container(x2 => x2.SelectConstructor(() => new BookRepository("")));" by "x.SelectConstructor<BookRepository>(() => new BookRepository("", ""));" but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    For<IBookRepository>()
        .Use<BookRepository>()
        .Named("SingleCtor").Ctor<string>().Is("rep name");

    For<IBookRepository>()
        .Use<BookRepository>()
        .Named("OtherCtor").Ctor<string>().Is("rep name").Ctor<string>().Is("db name");

    For<IService1>()
        .Use<Service1>()
        .Ctor<IBookRepository>().Is(x => 
        {
            return  x.GetInstance<IBookRepository>("OtherCtor");
        });

    For<IService2>()
        .Use<Service2>()
        .Ctor<IBookRepository>().Is(x => 
        {
            return  x.GetInstance<IBookRepository>("SingleCtor");
        });
```

Comment: Not work ozczecho, StructureMap don't find the correct constructor in each way ...